# visual studio wont build when there are no changes [up-to-date]

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

i have a visual studio 2019 project that i need to build over and over again as it triggers a post-build script. but if I build the project once, and then try again, the second time my build will just say "up to date" and wont trigger any post built steps

```
Build started...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

same thing happens if I trigger my build using command line `msbuild`

is there some way I can tell my VS2019 project to always build, regardless of if no files were changed since the last build? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `rebuild` which does a `clean` + `build`.

EDIT: If you only want to rebuild in order to execute your Post-build events, try modifying the "When to run the post-build event" to "Always" instead of "When the build succeeds". This should trigger your event even when no build happened because your files are up to date.

Comment: my worry with changing my post build step to always run is that my post build step relies on NuGet package dependencies to be downloaded, so i realize that if my build fails and it still runs post build script it could cause unexpected problems..

Comment: but rebuild could work